# File size comparison of each individual file in 'new' directory to a matching file in an 'old' directory

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare the lengths of individual files in an array and then copy/return any old files which may be smaller than corresponding new files to a new directory.

The issue I am having is how to compare each file's size *individually* to a corresponding file in another directory. Here's my code:

```
$oldFile = 'C:\Users\Old\Files\Path'
$newFile = 'C:\Users\New\Files\Path'

$newFileLength = foreach ($Elem in $newFiles) {
    $Elem.Length
}

foreach ($Elem in $oldFiles) {
    if ($newFileLength -gt $Elem.Length) {
        Copy-Item $Elem -Destination 'C:\Users\Difference\Directory'
    }
}
```

The part that results in error is the `if` condition. I don't think I'm properly calling individual file sizes, rather, I'm calling for the number of elements in my array. Basically, I need a way to compare new files I've received to their corresponding old file, and if the new file is bigger, copy the *old* file to a new directory.

Comment: By corresponding files, I assume the files have the same filename?

Comment: I can't imagine how you have written a whole script without testing any of it as you went along. `$oldFile` and `$newFile` are just strings, they're not directory listings. `foreach ($elem in $newFiles) {}` is iterating over nothing because it's a different variable name with an `s` on the end, and if it was the same name, it would be iterating over a single string and wouldn't do what you expect, and that would be clear as soon as you tried it in a shell to see if it was doing what you expect, way before you get to the copy stage..

Comment: Your `$newFileLength` is an array. Try to write `$newFileLength` to the console and see what does it return. You need to compare the individual elements of `$newFileLength`, like `$newFileLength[0]..$newFileLength[IndexOfLastItem]` with your `$Elem.Length` of `oldFiles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code:

- `$oldFile` and `$newFile` are just path strings, not collections of files.
- The variables used in your loops have a trailing "s" (`$oldFiles`, `$newFiles`), so they're different variables than the ones with the path strings (`$oldFile`, `$newFile`).
- The first loop would fill `$newFileLength` with an array of the `$newFiles` sizes. Comparing an array to a scalar (`$newFileLength -gt $Elem.Length`) would give you a list of the values from the array that are greater than the scalar. PowerShell interprets a non-empty list as `$true` and an empty list as `$false`, so your condition only becomes true if no size in the array is greater than the value the array is compared to.

To compare the individual sizes of the files in `$newFile` to a corresponding file in `$oldFile` you need to do the comparison *inside* that loop, not in a separate loop afterwards.

```
foreach ($elem in Get-ChildItem $newFile) {
    $referenceFile = Join-Path $oldFile $elem.Name
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $referenceFile) {
        if ($elem.Length -gt (Get-Item $referenceFile).Length) {
            Copy-Item ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm pretty new to using Powershell for most tasks, so this helps a lot.

For my understanding, could you explain what the third line (the if statement with the test-path and -literalpath) is doing? Also, I'm confused as to why the second line is needed.

Comment: @codegreens The second line builds the full path of a corresponding file in the other directory. The third line checks if that file actually exists.

Comment: Oh okay, cool. As far as the Copy-Item line, I used this:
`Copy-Item (Get-Item $referenceFile) -Destination '.\filepath' -Recurse`... Do I even need the -Recurse part? I feel like the foreach in the first line probably takes care of this, or was this a good way to do it?

Comment: Neither `Get-Item` nor `-Recurse` are needed here since you're copying a file and `Copy-Item` accepts string input.